# Is there a preferred way to characterize a cone in cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

In a Euclidean space, one can of course describe a cone using a generalization of polar coordinates, and since the de Rham cohomology spaces are themselves Euclidean spaces, one can do the same here.  For example, in the Kodaira-Thurston manifold $KT$, we have $b_{2}=4$.  If $(x,y,z,t)$ defines global coordinates for $H^{2}(KT;\mathbf{R})$, then it is not difficult to determine that the set of Hard Lefschetz symplectic forms on this manifold is the set determined by $xt-yz\neq 0$, $z\neq 0$, $t\neq 0$, and $z\neq t$.  Are there more sophisticated, more illuminating ways of describing the Hard Lefschetz cone in KT?

Comment: What on earth  is a Kodaira-Thurston manifold?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg "The Kodaira-Thurston manifold is a quotient of a nilpotent Lie group by a cocompact lattice." From this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1239

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It's a quotient of $\mathbf{R}^{4}$ by a certain $\mathbf{Z}^{4}$ action.  The bundle of 1-forms on the KT manifold has a global frame $\{e^{1},e^{2},e^{3},e^{4}\}$ with structure equations $de^{1}=de^{2}=de^{3}=0$ and $de^{4}=e^{23}=e^{2}\wedge e^{3}$.  Using these equations helps you determine all the de Rham cohomology groups for the KT manifold.

Comment: The $xt-yz\neq 0$ condition helps us identify with $GL(2,\mathbf{R})$, which has the homotopy type of $O(2)$, whose $2$ components are equivalent to $SO(2)$, which is homeo. to $S^{1}$.  But our cone is not just $xt-yz\neq 0$.  We must intersect this set with the spaces defined by $z\neq 0$, $t\neq 0$, $z\neq -t$.  All four of the sets which we are intersecting are Zariski-open-and-dense in $H^{2}$, hence Euclidean-open-and-dense.  Cohomology of our cone can be computed by Mayer-Vietoris and other standard theorems.  But otherwise, I'm lacking for inspiration here on characterizing my cone.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Sinister Cutlass.